# Telerik Silverlight Organization Chart

Tags: silverlight

Does any body know if Telerik has any control that supports drawing of Organization Charts.
If Telerik does not have, can anybody advise how can I draw organization chart with SilverLight.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Telerik does not have a control that supports drawing of organization charts

Answer (score 2):

Actually they do, but it is under ASP.NET AJAX. Here's the demo -> [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/orgchart/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Regards,
Garfield

Answer (score 0):

You can use template nodes in the TreeView control.  The Telerik Silverlight demo application has an example.  Use this URL:
[Templated Nodes](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeView/TemplatedNodes)

The sample is rudimentary but will serve as a good starting point

Regards
Jaco